# Proper if-else grouping Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to create a profile uploading function that if you do not upload an image if you're a boy you'll get `john.png` as default image and if you're a girl, you'll get `mary.png` as your default image. If you upload a photo, your profile picture will change to the newly uploaded image but should not DELETE either `john.jpg` or `mary.png`. And if you decide to upload a new one again, it should only replace the previously uploaded photo. So basically `john.jpg` or `mary.png` will never be overwritten and users can only have one photo in the database/system. This is what I have done so far:

```
$user = User::find($request->id);

if ($request->hasFile('user_image')) {
    if ($user->user_image != 'john.jpg' || $user->user_image != 'mary.png') {
        Storage::delete('public/user_images/' . $user->user_image);
    }

    $user->user_image = $newPhoto;
}
```

Unfortunately, this logic deletes `john.jpg` or `mary.png`, but if the user uploads again, it will replace the previous image that overwritten the default images.

This line `if ($user->user_image != 'john.jpg' || $user->user_image != 'mary.png')` will always give out one `true` and one `false`. Can someone assist me with the right logic?

```
EDIT:
```

Yes `&&` did the trick. Nicely done. My bad for not noticing this earlier on.

Comment: Try `&&` (and) instead of `||` (or)

Comment: It fixed my desired logic. Great